# update/insert data into table from table - ORA-00904

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-update, sql-insert

I am trying to insert/update data into table but I´m getting ORA-00904 - invalid identifier.

With tables definitions like this:

```
    CREATE TABLE "TST"."R0_RL_EST_SHARE" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER(19,0), 
    "BUILDING_SOCIETY_SHARE" CHAR(1 CHAR), 
    "EDITED_BY_USER" CHAR(1 CHAR), 
    "OBJECT_CREATED_ON" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "OBJECT_TYPE" VARCHAR2(2048 CHAR), 
    "OBJECT_UPDATED_ON" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "OBJECT_VERSION" NUMBER(19,0), 
    "REAL_ESTATE_SHARE_D" NUMBER(19,0), 
    "REAL_ESTATE_SHARE_N" NUMBER(19,0), 
    "MORTGAGE_OBJECT_ID" NUMBER(19,0), 
    "REAL_ESTATE_ID" NUMBER(19,0), 
    "SELLING_SHARE_OF_ID" NUMBER(19,0), 
    "PARTY_ID" NUMBER(19,0)
   )
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE "TST"."PARTY_SHARE" 
   (    "PARTY_ID" NUMBER(19,0), 
    "REAL_ESTATE_SHARE_ID" NUMBER(19,0)
   )
```

Both tables have thousands of rows. Column PARTY_ID in TST.R0_RL_EST_SHARE is empty - full of nulls. I need to insert PARTY_ID data from PARTY_SHARE to R0_RL_EST_SHARE with condition that ID in R0_RL_EST_SHARE is the same as R0_RL_EST_SHARE_ID in PARTY_SHARE.

I tried many things but it always ends with ORA-00904 - invalid identifier.

Here is my insert:

```
insert into R0_RL_EST_SHARE (PARTY_ID)
select PARTY_ID from PARTY_SHARE
where R0_RL_EST_SHARE.ID = PARTY_SHARE.REAL_ESTATE_SHARE_ID
```

and its error code:

```
Error starting at line : 6 in command -
insert into R0_RL_EST_SHARE (PARTY_ID)
select PARTY_ID from PARTY_SHARE
where "TST"."R0_RL_EST_SHARE".ID = PARTY_SHARE.REAL_ESTATE_SHARE_ID
Error at Command Line : 8 Column : 7
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "TST"."R0_RL_EST_SHARE"."ID": neplatný identifikátor
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Thanks for any help...

Comment: From table definition  of R0_RL_EST_SHARE above you can see there is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you are actually trying to `update` your data, not `insert`.

Here's one way:

```
update R0_RL_EST_SHARE 
set party_id = (
   select party_id 
   from PARTY_SHARE 
   where R0_RL_EST_SHARE.id = PARTY_SHARE.REAL_ESTATE_SHARE_ID)
```

- [Condensed SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f82c16/1)

Comment: Ok this works :-) Thank you. With all the attemps I was already confused about what I am actually doing...